# Closed Kaehler--Einstein surfaces are complex ball quotients

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a closed Kaehler manifold of real dimension 4 endowed with a Kaehler--Einstein metric of negative curvature. Is it true that $X$ is isomorphic, as a Kaehler manifold, to a quotient of a complex ball?

Comment: Which curvature do you want to be negative?

Comment: @abx say scalar curvature

Comment: Any surface with ample canonical bundle admits a Kähler--Einstein metric (Aubin-Yau), with constant negative scalar curvature. Those which are quotients of the complex ball form a minuscule part of this huge crowd.

Comment: @abx what if we require holomorphic sectional curvature to be negative? What if we require all sectional curvature to be negative?

Comment: Any compact complex surface of general type satisfies $c_1^2\le 3c_2$, with equality just when the surface is a ball quotient, a result of Yau and also of Miyaoka (the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality). For related results on singular ball quotients see Greb et al. https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08822

Comment: Hypersurfaces in CP3 of degree greater or equal than five admit KE metrics with negative Ricci. Nevertheless, these are simply connected and therefore any Riemannian metric on them must have a plane of positive sectional curvature.

Comment: It seems to be open whether a compact KE surface with strictly negative sectional curvature (or either bisectional or holomorphic sectional) is a ball quotient